# How to quickly change directores in VIM?

Tags: shell, vim

Is it possible to make vim work with another util that does it ?  CtrlP has limitation with directory search . Only thing I could find was a util like wcd .

However when I am trying to integrate vim to Wherever Change Directory ( a Norton Change Directory clone) I get into some basic issues .

wcd is a simple utility that takes an input and changes directory if it finds a single matching directory that contains input in its name . If there are multiple directories , it will give a simple select menu from which you could select the directory you want . It can also give the directory as output for piping purposes using -o option .

```
Example $wcd foo : Changes to /home/me/foo . [Since only 1 foo exists]
        $wcd bar : 1./home/me/bar/
                  2./home/me/simplebar/
                  Enter You Choice:
```

It works fine in terminal . Wondering how I could make vim to work with this utility .

There are 2 scenarios if I give :cd `wcd foo`

1. It can either give me a single result for `foo` , if there is only `foo` in my directory and vim changes
2. It could give multiple choices and I have to select one of them . Will vim allow that ?

The tricky thing is that vim has to just allow that program to run and complete and then get the output - even if that means open that program waits for user input . vim should  go to background like !command will show up a console .

Does anyone know if its possible to do `:cd !wcd foo` ? Or Equivalent ?

Comment: You should be more explicit about what that program does and how one could interact with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your edited your question I have another option for you https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim , have a look for

```
let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = 0
```

EDIT:

So you have chosen a very misleading question for your task :) You can use ctrlp with args, why not bind it to a mapping ? or using fuzzyfinder ?

You can and should set the "working dir" when working on a project, sure, but you should don't need open a specific directory in vim, you edit concrete files.
Maybe you can grab the file generated from fasd (automaticaly of course), and autogenerate some mappings for the most used directories, but I think this is a bad idea.

I personally use fasd + ctrlp for a long time with success, and I never needed open a specific directory in vim, except for setting the working dir, what ctrlp does automatically for me. But I'm only a small developer, maybe your use case is different.

EDIT part II:

your option would be

```
:h inputlist
```

check this out:

```
:echo inputlist(range(20))
```

You need to substitute the range20 with your command, also pass your wcd with args in there.

Comment: CtrlP is for files right ? Does it allow fuzzy search for directories ? I just want CtrlP concept for directory navigation . The problem is CtrlP has a concept of root , so you can't check for files elsewhere unless you change to that directory . And changing to that directory is the problem I am trying to solve :-)

Comment: I had a look at let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = 0 but wouldn't that mean ctrlp is going to be totally slow ?

Comment: So you have chosen a very misleading question for your task :)

Comment: Thats true , I mean I just want to quickly change directories in vim and I have a util called wcd !

Comment: Corrected the title :-)

Comment: Nice, thx, I updated my answer, but still I think you try to do it wrong. I would suggest run vim in server mode, and whenever you need to switch the working dir, spawn from there an instance of the client, I know, you not asked about this, so you can see above my suggestion for your problem. good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Command-line completion and the "wildmenu" are your friends.

You can use globs like `*` and `**`:

```
:cd **/foo<tab>
:cd **/*bar<tab>
```

See `:help starstar`.

With the options below,

```
set wildmenu
set wildignorecase
set wildmode=list:full
```

this is what it looks like when trying to `:cd` to a directory containing `dete` under my `~/.vim` directory:

```
:cd **/*dete<Tab>
```

[image: <Tab>]

You don't really need a plugin or an external utility for that.

Comment: Have you run it on your hard drive from your root directory and measured how long it takes to show something what has more matches ? It is not comparable to a tool that uses some caching behind. Even on my SSD drive it is way to slow... But I like the suggestion about not bloating the editor with useless extensions.

Comment: Yes I did it a couple of times, when I started to use Vim. Lack of experience is the only reason why anyone would start Vim from `/` or even from `/home/username/`. Vim is a text editor, not a file explorer: you are supposed to navigate to your project's directory with whatever you use for that and start a blank Vim from that directory or directly edit a file there.

Comment: exactly that's why I suggested run vim in server mode, and run it from diverse directories, it saves time opening the editor :) I agree it is not a file explorer, and mentioned it above, but it was not his question, in the question you see, he has two suggested dirs starting from the root, or more precisely from the home directory...

Answer (score 1):

If your look for an option to run vim on a fuzzy path from the shell, checkout https://github.com/clvv/fasd , on the page, vim usage is explained.

If you want simply use vim as an input pipe, us it with a dash:

```
tail -1000 /some/file | vim -
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a Vim plugin for Wcd. See: http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=191

Comment: Just fantastic to know there is a plugin even for WCD out there . Versatility is the word .